# Using phpdbg with the built-in php server?

Tags: php, debugging, phpdbg

I really like using the [php built in server](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php), and I really like the look of [phpdbg](http://phpdbg.com/).  It reminds me of [pry](http://pryrepl.org/) in Ruby land.  But I've been having trouble getting it to work.  Is it possible to run user `phpdbg` with the build in web server?

E.g., how I would *like* this to work:

1. placing `phpdbg_break();` *in the code*
2. running `php -S localhost:8000` *in the CLI*
3. loading the page/making the request that executes the code containing the `phpdbg_break();` *in the browser or through curl*
4. breaking out into a the phpdbg REPL *most likely in the same terminal/CLI instance that the built in server was started on*

When I try this, I get an error that `phpdbg_break();` is an undefined function.

Or else (if the above simply isn't possible), how do you use the "webmocking" [that the docs talk about](http://phpdbg.com/docs/simples) (at the bottom)?  How to you make a specific request with a specific URI?

Comment: Can't use the built-in debugger with the built-in webserver in a language pretty much designed to make web pages... Only PHP

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand properly, `phpdbg_break` is a function provided by the interpreter, and not by any extension. Instead of using the built-in PHP server, you should use the phpdbg server, and simulate a web request. See http://phpdbg.com/docs/mocking-webserver for information on how to mock the request and http://phpdbg.com/docs/simples to know how to run the debugger.

To make a request to the specific URI, I think you need to set `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` and optionally `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` to point to the URL you want to test. URI will be something like  '/path/to/file' and the querystring would be everything between the ? and the # in the URLs (ie ?page=2)

Thanks for pointing me to phpdbg, I didn't know that tool and it seems to be a very good one; I'll be testing it in the next days.

Comment: Just to clarify, maybe you don't even need to set $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; it will depend on how your framework routes a request to a Controller::method combination.

Answer (score 0):

I use [psysh](http://psysh.org/) for this same reason, just because it reminds me of `pry`. I actually use this snippet of code in place of `binding.pry` from `ruby`.

```
require "path_to_psysh_on_your_local_file_system";
\Psy\Shell::debug(get_defined_vars(), $this);
```

This is good enough for me. The only problem I'm having with this is:

1. Can't connect to an existing PHP process running in a `CGI`, with nginx     or apache servers
2. The built-in PHP server is single threaded and **very** slow, this drives me crazy sometimes

---

Other than that, I'm happy with my current workflow. I'd be happy to hear other folks opinions on this.

---

It even looks like there's some work going on about [Remote Debugging](https://github.com/bobthecow/psysh/issues/121), which may solve my issues.